# How to merge two nullable DateTime objects one contaning time other date I need into one object?

Tags: c#, datetime

I've got two `DateTime` objects. The `FetchTime` contains time `hh:mm:ss` I am insterested in, `FetchDate` contains date: year, month, day.

Example:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Time " + FetchTime);
Debug.WriteLine("Date " + FetchDate);
```

displays for example:

```
Time 2014-09-10 23:04:00
Date 2014-09-15 00:00:00
```

and I would like to get `DateTime` object which looks like that:

```
2014-09-15 23:04:00
```

I would like to merge those two into one or modify one of them. I thought it would be easy but I can't see almost any methods for `DateTime` object. Is it achievable or first I must convert `DateTime` to another type then convert it back? Finally, I have to have `DateTime` object because it is going to be added to SQL database .

**EDIT:**

I refer to nullable `DateTime`:  `DateTime? FetchDate, DateTime? FetchTime`.

[image]

Comment: Did you read the documentation on the `DateTime` object? There's Year, Month, Day, Hour, etc properties hanging off every DateTime object...

Comment: @tnw Did you see my edit there is none.

Comment: O_O That's Intellisense, not the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `Q: Why did Yoda visit Bank of America yesterday?`
`A: He needed a bank clone! (Loan)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [`DateTime` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var date = new DateTime(FetchDate.Year, FetchDate.Month, FetchDate.Day, 
    FetchTime.Hour, FetchTime.Minute, FetchTime.Second);
```

**Update:** It seems like you are using nullable `DateTime`. So you should get the underlying `DateTime` value using `Value` property.

```
var fetchDate = FetchDate.Value;
var fetchTime =  FetchTime.Value;
var date = new DateTime(fetchDate.Year, fetchDate.Month, fetchDate.Day, 
    fetchTime.Hour, fetchTime.Minute, fetchTime.Second);
```

Comment: Yes, I do use nullable.

Comment: Thank you, if I saw these properties I didn't asked the question, but I didn't know that nullable is a problem. I learnt something new.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you use the `?` suffix on a value type you will always need to call the `.Value` member before you can call any members on your type.

The `?` suffix is actually a special symbol for the compiler to transform your type reference from `T?` to `Nullable<T>`.  For additional details see the MSDN documentation for [Nullable`1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx).

For your example you will want to use the following to merge the values together.

```
new DateTime(
    FetchDate.Value.Year, 
    FetchDate.Value.Month,
    FetchDate.Value.Day, 
    FetchTime.Value.Hour,
    FetchTime.Value.Minutes,
    FetchTime.Value.Seconds)
```

Make sure to check for null using `== null` or `.HasValue` if you are concerned about null values, otherwise you will encounter a `System.InvalidOperationException`.

Answer (score 2):

For fun, here is another possible way:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2014, 9, 15);
DateTime datetime = new DateTime(2014, 9, 10, 23, 4, 0);

DateTime combined = date + datetime.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: This could be simplified using the `.TimeOfDay` property